# Passing data from fragment to activity android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent

I am trying to pass a String from a fragment to an activity in my app.I dont know what I am doing wrong but it seems the activity is not receiving the Intent that is being sent.THis is my code

Fragment  (tab2.class)

```
final String key = getRef(position).getKey();

                        viewHolder.setUsername(model.getUsername());
                        viewHolder.setDownloadUrl(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), model.getDownloadUrl());
                        viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {


                                Intent chatIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), Chat.class);
                                chatIntent.putExtra("key",key);
                                startActivity(chatIntent);
                                Log.v("intent", key);
```

Chat Activity(Chat.class)

```
Intent chatIntent = getIntent();
        String key = chatIntent.getStringExtra("key");
        Log.v("intents", key);
```

Comment: Code looks alright. Ensure that the value of key is set here: final String key = getRef(position).getKey();

Comment: THe value of the code is set there. It just seems the the data is not being retrieved in the Chat activtiy @difyzz

Comment: Put this line Log.v("intent", key); before this: startActivity(chatIntent);
Does it log the correct value of key?

Comment: yes please @difyzz

Comment: If the chat activity starts with your intent object then there's no question about not receiving the intent. If the intent object hasn't been received it would not have been started in the first place. So you're getting the intent object alright. 

One thing you should about key values is that try to declare them as static objects and reuse them like, `public static String KEY = "key";`

Comment: in your Chat.class, what method is the snippet in?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an interface to communicate between Activity and Fragment. The idea is basically to define an interface inside a given fragment and let the activity implement that interface.
Have a look at this tutorial : [HOW TO COMMUNICATE BETWEEN FRAGMENTS AND ACTIVITIES IN ANDROID](http://simpledeveloper.com/how-to-communicate-between-fragments-and-activities/)